# install wolframalpha libary in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, anaconda3, wolframalpha

I try to run this code

```
# Taking input from user
question = input('Question: ')

# App id obtained by the above steps
app_id = "XXXXX-57578YL87T"
# Instance of wolf ram alpha
# client class
client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)

# Stores the response from
# wolf ram alpha
res = client.query(question)

# Includes only text from the response
answer = next(res.results).text

print(answer)
```

however it tell me that there is no module named '' wolframalpha'
i am using anaconda3 as an environment ... do you know the commande that make me install wolframalpha in anaconda ?

Comment: You also have to import the library: `import wolframalpha` at the top after you install it using `pip install wolframalpha`. Note, if you used your actual App ID in the question, I suggest you to invalidate that and generate a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The [website](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/docpages/install.html#installation) recommends to use `pip`:

```
pip install wolframclient
```

However, there also is a package that can be installed using `conda`, see [here](https://anaconda.org/WolframResearch/wolframclient). It is the only package from the `WolframResearch` channel and can be installed with:

```
conda install -c wolframresearch wolframclient
```

Answer (score 0):

try pip install wolframalpha in the terminal.